# call a function from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, frontend, getusermedia

I am trying to call a function from within `navigator.mediaDevices.GetUserMedia` and it ain't working.

This is what I have

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
   __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
});
```

This is my function

```
function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    __log('Media stream created.' );
    __log("input sample rate " +input.context.sampleRate);
    __log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

    recorder = new Recorder(input, {
                  numChannels: 1
                });
    __log('Recorder initialised.');
  }
```

I'm trying to update this call, since before it was:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
     __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
});
```

and guess what, that works. But this new "mediaDevices", I can't make it work somehow. It says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: recorder is undefined
```

It is not making the call to the "startUserMedia" function. If I add a "alert("hello")" inside the function, it doesn't executes.

This works though:

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
      startUserMedia();
}).catch(function(err) {});
```

but it doesn't recognizes my recorder

`recorder = new Recorder(input, { numChannels: 1 });`

Anyone can lend a hand?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `navigator.getUserMedia` format in the new `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` format; which will not work since the later returns a promise instead of expecting callbacks

Comment: see this for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer thanks to Derek there.

```
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    audio_context = new AudioContext;
    __log('Audio context set up.');

    if (navigator.mediaDevices) { // if navigator.mediaDevices exists, use it
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(startUserMedia, function(e) {
          __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
        });
    } else {
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
          __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
        });
    }
```

This way I can check both if the browser supports getUserMedia or not. Either way, it fires the prompt that asks the user for the browser's media permission.

The StartUserMedia function gets called in both instances.